# comparator сортирует не так, как задумано

Tags: java, java-stream

Делаю домашнее задание, в потоке фильтрую элементы коллекции List. Использую Comparator для сортировки элементов по алфавитному порядку. Смотрю на код и элементы должны отсортированы в таком порядке:

1. Альбина
2. Бегемот.
3. Ева.

Код:

```
public class Main2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
        users.add(new User("Кристина", 25));
        users.add(new User("Бегемот", 32));
        users.add(new User("Динозавр", 45));
        users.add(new User("Ева", 18));
        users.add(new User("Альбина", 27));
        users.add(new User("Жираф", 68));
        users.add(new User("Мама", 45));
        
        users.stream()
                .sorted(Comparator.comparing(User::getName))
                .filter(user -> user.getAge() < 35)
                .limit(3)
                .map(user -> user.getName())
                .forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Класс User:

```java
public class User {
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", age=" + age +
                '}';
    }

    public User(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

А результат получается

Альбина

Кристина

Бегемот

Объясните пожалуйста, почему так

Comment: У меня выводится всё так, как и задумано. Возможно, если в вашей программе несколько методов `main()` в разных классах, и до этого вы тренировались с другим методом, то сейчас запускаете по-прежнему его, а не тот, который привели в вопросе.

Comment: Нет нет, запускаю Main2, сортировка неправильная из-за глюка или что?

Comment: Проблема не воспроизводится, имена _в представленном коде_ выводятся в нужном порялке `Альбина, Бегемот, Ева`.  Вывод в порядке `Aльбина, Kристина, Бегемот` _может_ получиться, если первые два имени начинаются с _английской/латинской_ буквы.

Comment: Переписал слова заново на кириллице, и результат тот-же(не правильный). Пару дней назад у меня были проблемы с UTF-8. Может от туда ноги растут...

Comment: Представленный Вами код [работает как ожидается](https://www.jdoodle.com/a/6T0q)...

Comment: @poronoy, объясните подробнее, что значит "проблемы с UTF-8"? Покажите код вашего класса `User`, дело может быть в каких-то деталях его реализации.  В _представленном на данный момент коде_ указанная вами проблема НЕ воспроизводится.

Comment: @NowhereMan компилятор не мог воспроизвести буквы на кириллице.  Какие манипуляции я сделал, чтобы "починить" UTF-8, К сожалению я уже не помню

Comment: То есть у вас в вашей IDE эта проблема остаётся и после пересоздания проекта с данным кодом?

Comment: @NowhereMan, если вы про UTF-8. То проблемы пока нет, если вы про сортировку компаратора, то это уже не важно, код правильный,. Было интересно, разобраться